# Is sort( ) poor at rearraing because it returns the order as numeric vector?

Tags: r

I quickly learned that arrange() from {dplyr} is a better for my analysis than sort().  Just curious it is because the object returned by sort() function is of numeric class.  Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=round(rpois(10,10)), b=LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors = F)
df
    a b
1  13 A
2   7 B
3  11 C
4   6 D
5  10 E
6  10 F
7  10 G
8   6 H
9  11 I
10  9 J
```

I found out that arrange() is good at rearranging if I want to sort the data frame.

```
arrange(df, desc(a))
    a b
1  13 A
2  11 C
3  11 I
4  10 E
5  10 F
6  10 G
7   9 J
8   7 B
9   6 D
10  6 H
```

If I try to order the original data frame, what is sort doing?

```
df[sort(df[,1]),]
      a    b
6    10    F
6.1  10    F
7    10    G
9    11    I
10    9    J
10.1  9    J
10.2  9    J
NA   NA <NA>
NA.1 NA <NA>
NA.2 NA <NA>
```

So I am think it is generally not a good idea to rearrange with a numeric vector.

```
sort(df[,1])
[1]  6  6  7  9 10 10 10 11 11 13
class(sort(df[,1]))
[1] "numeric"
```

I would like to know what happened when I tried to rearrange with sort().
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `order` to provide the index.

```
df[order(-df$a),]
```

If we are using `sort`, use the `index.return` option as TRUE

```
df[sort(df$a, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)$ix,]
```

Comment: This is somewhat tangential to the question, but there is a downside to using order. `sort` lets you do partial sorting, (`sort.list` has partial as an argument, but it's not supported yet)

Comment: @Shape Thanks for the comments.  Good to know about the partial sorting